# fail to create environment in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

i am trying to create a new environment in conda but it keep failing with the following error, any suggestion on how to fix this? Thanks! i am using: conda create -name deeplearning

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - deeplearning

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: `conda create --name` instead of `conda create -name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type in -name deeplearning, conda will think you want to install the library "deeplearning", that is why you see this error. You can either type -n or --name as the correct command. -n is the shortcut for --name.

```
conda create --name deeplearning
```

you can get more details on commands by typing

```
conda --help
```

and

```
conda create --help
```

Answer (score 1):

`conda create --name deeplearning`